# JUnit End to End Integration Testing

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am doing an End To End integration testing with JUnit and Spring (not Boot). I would like to test from a POST request all the way to the db. Here is my test:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextHierarchy({
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class),
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = OrderHdrController.class)
})
@ActiveProfiles("Test")
public class FilterActivityTest4 {

    MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).dispatchOptions(true).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testActivity() {

        OrderSearchDto orderSearchDto = new OrderSearchDto();
        OrderSearchPanelDto orderSearchPanelDto = new OrderSearchPanelDto();
        orderSearchPanelDto.setActivityTypes(Arrays.asList("TAKEOVER","DELIVERY"));
        orderSearchDto.setOrderSearchPanelDto(orderSearchPanelDto);

        try {
            MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(post("/orders/getOrderList")
                    .content(asJsonString(orderSearchDto))).andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andReturn();
            String content = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
            System.out.print(content);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static String asJsonString(final Object obj) {
        try {
            final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            final String jsonContent = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
            return jsonContent;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }  
}
```

And here is my TestConfig.class:

```
    @Autowired
    private OrderManager orderManager;

    @Bean
    public OrderManager OrderManager() {
        return orderManager;
    }
```

And in my OrderHdr controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/orders")
public class OrderHdrController {
    @Autowired
    private OrderManager orderManager;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getOrderList", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, Object> getOrderTables(OrderSearchDto orderSearchDto) {
         ...
         orderHdrTables = orderManager.findAllOrders(orderSearchDto);
         ...
    }
}
```

But my orderManager object is null in my controller, causing a Null Pointer Exception when I run the test.

Question is: How to I instantiate the orderManager object? Is it by "Autowired"?

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

You have to Instantiate the `OrderManager` Object by `Autowired`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you elaborate with code? I have instantiated it with @Autowired.

Answer (score 0):

The test code you provided does not actually perform an End-to-End integration test, as it is just testing the Web Layer for your Spring application (the controller parts). It does not boot the whole Spring context which would allow you to inject any beans into your test code.

You can remove your `TestConfig` and mock the `OrderManager` bean with:

```
@MockBean
private OrderManager orderManager;
```

This allows you to control the behavior of your `OrderManager` using Mockito. All of this is described in the [following Spring guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/) at the end

Comment: Hi @rieckpil Thanks for your answer. MockBean is from Spring Boot. How about Spring Framework? How do I mock it?